# Vercel not caching assets (image, video, audio)

Tags: reactjs, caching, optimization, next.js, vercel

I have a page with tons of static assets (image, video, audio) which affects really bad the page performance.

When checking the network tab, I find out that all those assets are not cached (the cache control is `public, max-age=0, must-revalidate`) despite the fact that I use Vercel for deployment.

Am I missing something or are there any other ways to optimize more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vercel caches your content at the edge using their Edge Network.

From Vercel's [Caching](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching) documentation:

> The Vercel Edge Network caches your content at the edge in order to
> serve data to your users as fast as possible.
>
> **Static caching is automatic for all deployments.** This means that no
> changes need to be made to headers.

However, you can still customise it by overriding the `Cache-Control` header.

> By default we return a `Cache-Control` header containing `public, max-age=0, must-revalidate` to prevent clients (e.g. browsers) from
> caching the file locally. This gives you the most flexibility as users
> get the latest file from our Global CDN immediately after deploying.
> This can be overridden with the [Headers](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#project-configuration/headers) property in your `vercel.json`
> file.

Comment: I still can't get it to work, ssr is caching ok, but images using next/image component never get cached. I tried to set minimumCacheTTL in next.config and it also made no difference

Comment: @LuizHenriqueGuerra `next/image` image optimisation has its own [caching mechanism](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#caching-behavior). In theory setting the `minimumCacheTTL` value in the config would allow you to control it. I'd recommend asking a new, separate question with specific details about your setup including the `next.config.js` file.